# How to always refresh token using Keycloak

Tags: refresh, token, keycloak

I need to refresh token after updating the user information in my service provider for immediately refreshing data on the view. I tried to add "always-refresh-token: true" to keycloak.json but it didn't get me a successfull result. Can anybody help?

Comment: Using keycloak.js the example from Redhat does this:
      var reloadData = function () {
        keycloak.updateToken(10)
                .success(loadData)
                .error(function() {
                    document.getElementById('customers').innerHTML = '<b>Failed to load data.  User is logged out.</b>';
                });
    }
The reload function always calls keycloak.update which I think sends the refresh token to keycloak.

Comment: @AntKutschera I just stumbled upon this topic. Wouldn't it be odd to refresh token from Single Page Application? Is refresh token used to acquire new access token or the life of existing access token is extended?